# changing filesystem format from xfs to ext4 without losing data

Tags: linux, ubuntu, xfs, ext4, jfs

I have a fresh Lucid Lynx (Ubuntu 10.04) running on a laptop. where I defined the filesystems as:

- mount point / on ext4 (46 Gb)
- mount point /home on jfs (63 GB)
- swap as 3 Gb

I left the machine over night to do some task, without AC power supply. next day in the morning I found it on standby, task completed, but filesystem was not reachable. it gave me I/O error

it seems that there is a problem with jfs and standby.

anyways, to avoid any hassle, I want to move this mount point from jfs format to ext4.

can I do this without losing data and without the need to place the data in a temporary location until transformation is done?

sorry to mention that, but I recall back in the windows days, we would change a FAT16 to FAT32 or a FAT32 to NTFS without having to lose the data. I hope this is available on Linux.

**Update**
The /home filesystem was xfs not jfs, and it seems there is a bug with this filesystem for some reason, I had to re-install the OS twice until I ended up with ext4 for the entire /

However, as a conclusion, it seems that there is no way to make a conversion

Comment: Make a backup and restore.  Any other method would not be used commonly enough to be considered safe.  Oh, and for the record FAT32->NTFS was not always without problems.

Comment: @Zoredache: (or anyone else with info) What would be the appropriate backup utility?  I think one might have to use `tar` or something similar, since my impression is that `dump` is filesystem specific.

Comment: I need to convert my root (/) fs, a reiser4, to ext4, and a friend of mine recommended using cp or even tar on that. I've read `man cp` and I'll try it soon, the suggested method is to mount the target fs on another OS, if possible a live one, format the partition and then just extract/copy the data back. Since you aren't booting through that OS, you won't have any trouble backing it up, since devices node files and other special files won't be mounted at that time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i am unaware of any way to non-destructively convert a file system. this does not mean it is impossible, but i would put it at very low odds.

you can, for example, convert from `ext2` to `ext3` without wiping the disk, and from `ext3` to `ext4`.

but to go from something like `jfs` to `ext4` seems highly improbable, without first copying your `/home` files to another partition or external hard disk.

even then, you would want to create a new user on your system, with a home directory somewhere like `/tmp/tempuser` or copy your configurations for your user, usually the 'dot' files (files beginning with `.`) in your home directory to a new location off `/home` and updating `/etc/passwd` to use the new home directory, so you can log in as a normal user while you're performing this update.

then, back up your files, unmount `/home` and format it using `/sbin/mkfs.ext4` or whatever tool you plan to use. mount the fresh partition at `/home` and copy your files back.

also, i would recommend something 'intelligent' like `rsync` to copy your files, to assure you preserve your permissions and all that jazz.

Answer (score 8):

[fstransform](https://github.com/cosmos72/fstransform) converts between ext2, ext3, ext4, jfs, minix, xfs, reiserfs.

I see it in Debian repositories, so it probably is also available in other Debian-based distributions.

Comment: There is more info about this project on [github](https://github.com/cosmos72/fstransform)

Comment: If you are an openSUSE user and want to use this tool, you can download/install using the 'one-click' method here: https://software.opensuse.org/download.html?project=filesystems&package=fstransform

Answer (score 2):

You can try http://tzukanov.narod.ru/convertfs/ When I used it a few years ago it worked in one case and trashed the file system in another case.